# In Team Fortress 2, what is "telefragging", and how is it done?

Tags: team-fortress-2, terminology, tf2-engineer

On my server stats page, there's a kill category that is called "telefrag". I don't have any.  What is this, and how is it done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a practical use for the otherwise rather uncommon event, specific to the TF2 setting. It uses the fact that a disguised spy can use enemy teleporters and perform telefrags on the opposing team when coming out of them. Doesn't work that well on experienced engineers, but can catch inexperienced ones off guard.

This only works if the engineer is near the teleporter exit, turtling behind a sentry that has the exit near it.

As a spy, work your way to the enemy teleporter entrances. They're usually right outside the spawn. Make sure you're disguised and that the teleporter is charged and ready for use. Sap the teleporter and stand over the sapped teleporter before the sapper is removed. If the engineer is standing over the exit as he's removing the sapper (as inexperienced engineers often are), you will immidately teleport through the teleporter as the sapper is removed and will perform a telefrag on the engineer. This strategy also has the added benefit of leaving you disguised and ready to sap all the buildings of the now dead engieer that happen to be near by, including the teleporter you just used.

Some inexperienced engineers might also build these tight clusters of buildings, where the teleporter will be right behind the sentry. In these nowadays rather rare cases you can perform the telefrag without even using the sapper, altough there is a risk of the engineer not holding his place all the time.

Comment: You can also kill enemies that happen to be walking over your teleport exit, but it requires some good timing or a clumsy enemy.

Comment: True. I wrote this answer rather as a suppliment to all the others, so I left that part out. Now that it's a selected answer, I might edit it to include the basic info of telefragging as well.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the term originates with Doom. What they found was that if a player used a teleporter and teleported inside another player, it would frag the second player, hence telefrag (teleport frag).

Comment: Of course, if the Spy isn't careful, they can also get telefragged.  I saw this a few days ago on freight when a Spy sapped my Sentry and Dispenser, then ran backwards from me while shooting at me, and ran into a wall... where my teleporter was, and a demo teleported through it. :D  Strangely, the engineer gets the kill, not the person who teleported, unless it's a Spy teleporting through an enemy teleporter.

Answer (score 20):

A telefrag happens when a player stands on or near a teleporter exit while an enemy player uses the entrance. What happens then is that the player on the exit dies and the teleport goes through successfully.

It stops spawn-camping very well. It is not possible to telefrag allies unless Friendly Fire is on.

**Note**: Even übercharged players can be telefragged.

---

[image: telefrag-stick-figure]

This is actually a [common term in gaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frag_(video_gaming)#Telefrag), not only related to Team Fortress 2.

Comment: @ArdaXi lol at simultaneous answers.

Comment: How did y'all get exactly the same answers?  Should y'all mention the source where you got the input from?

Comment: In TF2 it is not necessary for the teleporter to be an enemy teleporter, only for the player being teleported to be an enemy - disguised spies can telefrag players that are on the same team as the teleporter.

Comment: @Oak - So then potentially, could a spy get to the enemy spawn, sap the entrance, stand on it, and wait for the engineer to remove the sapper from the other end? Would the engie be close enough to the exit in most cases to get fragged?

Comment: @Jeffery [That case actually just got its own separate answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5829/in-team-fortress-2-what-is-telefragging-and-how-is-it-done/5838#5838)

Comment: How does telefragging stop spawn camping?

Comment: Side Note:  The only players that can get telefrag kills are engineers and spies.  Engineers get a kill if anyone on their team telefrags an enemy using the Engineer's teleporter.  Spies get a kill if they telefrag an enemy using an enemy teleporter.

Comment: @Powerlord - I'm fairly sure the server registers it as a suicide, not as a kill for the engineer.

Comment: @ArdaXI: That would be incorrect.  It definitely registers it as a kill for the engineer.  One of the reasons I knew the Spy in my August 25th anecdote was telefragged is because it showed in my kill messages in the upper right, with the skull kill icon.  If it had registered as a suicide, it would have had extra text in the kill message ("was finished off by" I believe).

Comment: Hm. Wikipedia link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

There are two different ways this can happen in TF2:

**Case 1:** 
An enemy stands on your team's teleporter exit and is telefragged by someone on your team using the teleporter.

**Case 2:** 
Someone from your team is standing on your team's teleporter exit, and is telefragged by a disguised enemy spy using the teleporter.

**What you should remember:** 
Standing on top of a teleporter exit is a *bad idea*, regardless of whose team it belongs to. If you're camping a teleporter exit, avoid using melee weapons, as they may cause you to get too close to it. Longer-ranged melee (Eyelander / Scotsman's Skullcutter / Shovel) is slightly safer.

Answer (score 3):

Telefragging is when you kill an enemy by stepping on the teleporter.

IF you are at the exit and an enemy uses the entrance, then you die.

Comment: Since normal enemies cannot take you teleporters, I guess this is limited to disguised spies?

Comment: It's actually kinda reversed. The enemy is on the exit.

Comment: @ArdaXi sorry, I swapped subject and object in the two sentences :-p.